# Tensorflow model file size varies significantly

Tags: tensorflow

I am using a tensorflow framework and I have noticed that there are major variances in the size of the tensorflow model files.

For example the framework provides 2 models:

- one of pretrained model to be used with fine tuning for example
- and one which contains an untrained version.

They both have a size of `172.539 kb`

When I apply *fine tuning* in my model with some minor changes in the graph (there is a module in framework for that) and save my model the size remains essentially the same: `178.525 kb`.

First, I am bit surprised that my fine-tuned model is somewhat bigger since I change just the last layer from 21 to 14 classes so I would expect a somewhat smaller model file size but since the difference is so little I didn't pay attention.

But when I *trained* the same model using the same model file (the pretrained one I mean) and saved the model in disk the file size is quite different: `340.097 kb`. By the term *train* I mean I allow the network to modify all parameter not just the parameters of the last layer.

The model that is being implemented is a variation of **resnet** for *semantic image segmentation* (if can someone deduct the expected model file size from the model itself).

So, my questions are why I have such a variance in the model file sizes and how come my saved fine-tuned model is larger than the original model? Is there a way to include/exclude parameters in the model to be saved?

*P.S.1 Some information that might be handy:*

1. I am using *tensorflow v2* model saving while I think the framework files use *v1*. I am not sure how to identify this besides the fact that the former produces 3 files.
2. The framework is called tensorflow-deeplab-resnet and can be found [here](https://github.com/DrSleep/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet) and the models are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_rootXHuswsZ0E4Mjh1ZU5xZVU).

P.S.2 
I am not sure stack overflow it 's the right place for this question either.

Comment: Is it possible that you keep _adding_ stuff to your graph, instead of replacing it? In the fine tuning, maybe you are adding new weights but still storing the old ones in the saved file? And after restoring, maybe you are recreating everything and that's what you get close to twice the size? You can check out [tf.graph_util.extract_sub_graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/extract_sub_graph) and [tf.graph_util.remove_training_nodes](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/remove_training_nodes).

Comment: I definitely  have redundant operations in my model. Any example how to use those  functions?

Comment: I'm realising that those functions work over [`tf.GraphDef`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphDef) objects, which is useful to save models as a protobuf, but not directly to save checkpoints. Maybe you could use the [Graph Editor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.graph_editor) module, although I don't know much about it (maybe use [`get_backward_walk_ops`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/graph_editor/get_backward_walk_ops) with the outputs?).

Answer (score 1):

That is because, when training models and saving them, Tensorflow will also save the gradients of your ops.

So allowing training on the last layer will increase the size of your saved model a little. And allowing training on the whole model will essentially double the size of the save file because each op will have its gradients saved.

Comment: But this shouldn't affect the provided pretrained model also? This saved model did not include gradients?

Comment: If they provide a pre-trained model, they probably removed the gradients from the save file since you're not going to need them for testing. It is only useful to continue training the model at a later time.

Comment: @Eypros An easy way to check whether you have gradients saved is to open the `.index` file created by Tensorflow saver with a text editor (`gedit` for example) and search for `gradient`.

Comment: My `.index` file appears to be binary not text file

Comment: It is but there is still some readable text in there for the name of the variables

Comment: Anyway I don't have any `gradient` in it either. Meaning no gradient is stored?

Comment: @Eypros Actually, it depends on how your gradient operation is named. For me, I used a `variable_scope` called `gradient_op`. For you, the name might be different but I can assure you that gradients are saved during training.